# How to localize open graph meta tags, such as og:description

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-opengraph

I have a webpage that I want to share with other people(invitation link). I need to localize meta tags, such as og:description and og:title, so if someone with EN lang sends this link to his EN friend, he would see a small description of this site in EN language (even before opening the page, In the link itself) . And if someone with DE lang sends a link to his DE speaking friend, he would see DE preview of this site.
I've tried to google it really hard, but failed.
Is there a way to add another og:description using different localization on the same webpage?

I have this:
< meta property="og:description" content="some EN description">
I need to add another description in a different language